# C#: Sending emails to personal mails and group mails (not working for group mails)

Tags: c#, .net, email

In an ASP.NET/C# application (mvc3) I want to be able to send Mail.

This is the function I am using for that:

```
    public static void SendEmail(string fromEmail, string fromName, string toEmail, string toName, string subject, string emailBody, bool isBodyHtml, string[] attachments, string emailServer, int portNumber, string loginName, string loginPassword)
    {
        // setup email header
        System.Net.Mail.MailMessage mailMessage = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage();

        // Set the message sender
        // sets the from address for this e-mail message.
        mailMessage.From = new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress(fromEmail, fromName);
        // Sets the address collection that contains the recipients of this e-mail message.
        string[] toEmailList = toEmail.Split(',');
        string[] toNameList = toName.Split(',');
        for (int i = 0;i<toEmailList.Length;++i) 
        {
            mailMessage.To.Add(new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress(toEmailList[i],toNameList[i]));
        }
      //  mailMessage.To.(new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress(toEmail, toName));

        // sets the message subject.
        mailMessage.Subject = subject;
        // sets the message body.
        mailMessage.Body = emailBody;
        // sets a value indicating whether the mail message body is in Html.
        // if this is false then ContentType of the Body content is "text/plain".
        mailMessage.IsBodyHtml = isBodyHtml;

        // add all the file attachments if we have any
        if (attachments != null && attachments.Length > 0)
            foreach (string _Attachment in attachments)
                mailMessage.Attachments.Add(new System.Net.Mail.Attachment(_Attachment));

        // SmtpClient Class Allows applications to send e-mail by using the Simple Mail Transfer Protocol (SMTP).
        System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient _SmtpClient = new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient(emailServer);

        //Specifies how email messages are delivered. Here Email is sent through the network to an SMTP server.
        _SmtpClient.DeliveryMethod = System.Net.Mail.SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;

        // Some SMTP server will require that you first authenticate against the server.
        // Provides credentials for password-based authentication schemes such as basic, digest, NTLM, and Kerberos authentication.
        System.Net.NetworkCredential _NetworkCredential = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(loginName, loginPassword);
        _SmtpClient.UseDefaultCredentials = false;

        _SmtpClient.Credentials = _NetworkCredential;
        _SmtpClient.Port = portNumber;
        //Let's send it
        try
        {
            _SmtpClient.Send(mailMessage);
            mailMessage.Dispose();
            _SmtpClient = null;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }

    }
```

Everything works fine for personal Emails.

**The Problem is this:**

If one of the TO Emails (the emails I am sending this to) is a group Email, it does not send to it.

By Group Email, I mean an Email that have multiple contacts attached to it, and they all receive the message when someone send it to that email.

Example of Group Email

If someone send an email to MyFamily@somedomain.com all my family receives it.

How can I make it work for all kind of email not just personal emails.

Thanks a lot for any help

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with my personal Google Apps Domain. But the problem was in the configuration of the Group Email and not in the c# code.

Did you check your permissions on the Group Email? Often you can define, who can send Emails to this Group Email. So you have to use the right email address or to reconfigure the permissions. Normally all members of the group can send emails to the group.